# Fixed Nav Menu Height using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I want to make my Nav Menu height to be fixed. Using the below HTML and CSS Code.

I'm putting `height: 100%` but still doesnt work.

Below image is the layout that I want to achieve.

[image: design requirements]

```css
html,
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navigation {
    width: 300px;
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
    background-color: #999;
}

.submenu a:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}

.submenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should give your body and html a height of 100%
At the moment navigation is trying to take height of the surrounding container but it is not set.

```
 html, body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Here is a fiddle to show the working example [fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqL3s5d1/)

Comment: Thank you...for the response but that menu is inside a div...        
#wrapper {
 border: 1px solid silver;
 width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
 height: 100%;
}
*html #wrap {height:100%}
#inner-wrap{padding-bottom:85px; }
#inner-wrap:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
 
}
* html #inner-wrap {
    height:1px;

This is the HTML CODE 

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header class="header-basic-light"> 
     <div id="inner-wrap">
<nav class="navigation">